# export buttons (print and excel) are not coming in datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, datatable

I have one datatable where table data is coming dynamically by clicking on search button.Data will come between FromData to Todata.For Every searcg button click i want table to be clear so that new data will not append to old data and to clear table I am using `$('#yourTableId').dataTable().fnClearTable();` 
But the problem is due this "fbClearTable();" export button (print and excel) are not coming.

```js
var inittable = function() {
    var finance = $('#financetbl');
    var ofinance = finance.dataTable({
                // Internationalisation. For more info refer to http://datatables.net/manual/i18n
                "language": {
                    "aria": {
                        "sortAscending": ": activate to sort column ascending",
                        "sortDescending": ": activate to sort column descending"
                    },
                    "emptyTable": "No data available in table",

                    "zeroRecords": "No matching records found"
                },
                buttons: [{
                   extend: 'print',
                   className: 'btn dark btn-outline'
               }, {
                   extend: 'excel',
                   className: 'btn yellow btn-outline '
               }],
                responsive: false,
                //"ordering": false, disable column ordering 
                //"paging": false, disable pagination
                colReorder: {
                reorderCallback: function () {
                    console.log( 'callback' );
                }
            },
    
    "order": [
                    [0, 'asc']
                ],
                "lengthMenu": [
                    [5, 10, 15, 20, -1],
                    [5, 10, 15, 20, "All"] // change per page values here
                ],
                // set the initial value
                "pageLength":10,
                 "dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12'B>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r><'table-scrollable't><'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>", // horizobtal scrollable datatable
                // Uncomment below line("dom" parameter) to fix the dropdown overflow issue in the datatable cells. The default datatable layout
                // setup uses scrollable div(table-scrollable) with overflow:auto to enable vertical scroll(see: assets/global/plugins/datatables/plugins/bootstrap/dataTables.bootstrap.js). 
                // So when dropdowns used the scrollable div should be removed. 
                //"dom": "<'row' <'col-md-12'T>><'row'<'col-md-6 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-6 col-sm-12'f>r>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",
            });
        }
```

```js
$('#paymentdetails').click(function(){
     if( $(".datepickerInputFROM").val() > $(".datepickerInputTO").val())
      {
      alertify.alert('From Date should not be greater than  To Date')
      return false;
      $(".datepickerInputFROM").val ="";
      }
     var getData = basePath +'AdminFinance/GetStudentPaymentsForDate/?FromDate='+$(".datepickerInputFROM").val() + '&ToDate='+$(".datepickerInputTO").val()
       
       if (($(".datepickerInputFROM").val() == "") && ($(".datepickerInputTO").val() == ""))
       { 
                            alertify.alert('Please select dates to proceed.')
       return false;
       } else if (($(".datepickerInputFROM").val() == "") || ($(".datepickerInputTO").val() == ""))
       { 
                            alertify.alert('Please select dates to proceed.')
       return false;
       }
    
                     
                   
    $.ajax({
                        url: getData 
                        , async: false
                        , success: function (response) {
                           //  alert(response[0]);
                            //$('#financetbl tbody').empty();
       $("#financetbl").dataTable().fnClearTable();
       
                           // if (response.resultCourse != '' && response[0]!= 'null') {
          if (response.length > 0) {
                             var tr;
                                 for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                                 tr = '<tr>'
                                 tr += "<td>" + response[i].transactionDate+ "</td>";
                                 tr += "<td>" + response[i].applicationNumber+ "</td>";
                                 tr += "<td>" + response[i].applicantName+ "</td>"
                              
                                 tr += '</tr>'
                                $("#financetbl").dataTable().fnAddData($(tr));
        }
        
        inittable();
                               console.log(response)
         
                            }
                            else {
        console.log(response)
                                alertify.alert("Error : No Payments Details Found");
        
        
        
                            }
                        }
                    });
    });
```

Whenever i remove `$('#yourTableId').dataTable().fnClearTable();` from code buttons are coming but after including `$('#yourTableId').dataTable().fnClearTable(); buttons are coming.`

Answer (score 0):

I handle with these problem follow this way:

$('#tableId').dataTable().fnDestroy();

you can try it !

Comment: it will destroy the table and by this also buttons are not coming.

Comment: Yes，After request data, you call datatable again . I think it can reach your  request

Comment: I mean, you use that method, of course, you're gonna have to clear the data in datatable. Button is also part of your initialization data，So，it will not come. But if you change your method like I said, it could solve your problem

Comment: by using $('#tableId').dataTable().fnDestroy(); also i am not getting buttons

Comment: I mean , you should change your mind. Once data changed, you should destroy dataTable and then call  dataTable again.

Comment: could you please provide me any fiddle example ?